# Vertically center li's with different heights

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create rows of images, with 3 images in each row. All this data is dynamic, but below is some example HTML and CSS:

```
ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; width: 900px; }

li { margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 280px; display: inline-block;
     text-align: center; }

<ul>
    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/FcRwL.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/VLwWb.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/euevl.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/VLwWb.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/euevl.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/FcRwL.png" /></li>
</ul>
```

Here it is in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZxPG3/

So my problem is that all the images appear to be vertically-aligned at the bottom. This happens because the height of the `li` is equal to the image contained inside - it doesn't equal the height of the `ul`. I can't set the height of the `li` to a specific value, since I never know what the height of the images will be.

Is there a way to set the `li` to equal the height of the `ul`, and then vertically center the image inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give `vertical-align:middle;` to the `UL` **AND** the `LI`

http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/WKkzK/3/

Works for me in FF, Chrome, Opera, Safari and IE7-9

Note that IE7 needs a CSS hack to work

Didn't test in IE6

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZxPG3/4/

You need to know the height of the tallest image, though. (put in `line-height` of the `LI`s)

Answer (score 0):

Vertically centering in CSS is hard. It is a problem its design.

Here is an [interesting article](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/) about different methods of vertical centering.

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxPG3/3/) using `display:table-cell;` and `vertical-align:middle;` There are problems, however. It doesn't wrap, and doesn't work in old versions of IE.

Also, consider looking into [CSS3 Flexbox](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/).

Answer (score 0):

And another alternative, where you don't need to set the height, is to make use of `display: table-row` on the `UL` and `table-cell` on the `LI`s, coupled with `vertical-align: middle` on them.

In action: http://jsfiddle.net/ZxPG3/5/

Comment: Only problem there is that even with the width of the `ul` set, it doesn't wrap.

Comment: So if you need wrapping, go for the `vertical-align` method.